# If $A$ symmetric then $\max_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|\le \lambda_{\max}$

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in S_n^+(\mathbb R)$ with eigenvalues $0\le\lambda_1\le\dots\le \lambda_n$,

I want to show : $$\max_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|\le \lambda_n$$

I am stuck. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This amounts to say that $|a_{i,j}|\leqslant\lambda_n$ for all $i,j$. First of all, we have using the min-max theorem ($A$ is symetric) that
$$ \lambda_n=\sup_{\|X\|=1}{}^tXAX\geqslant {}^tE_iAE_i=a_{i,i}. $$
Now let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X_{\lambda}=E_i+\lambda E_j$, then
$$ {}^tX_{\lambda}AX_{\lambda}=\lambda^2a_{i,i}+2\lambda a_{i,j}+a_{j,j}\geqslant 0 $$
because $A$ is positive therefore $4a_{i,j}^2-4a_{i,i}a_{j,j}\leqslant 0$ and $a_{i,j}^2\leqslant a_{i,i}a_{j,j}\leqslant\lambda_n^2$ thus $|a_{i,j}|\leqslant\lambda_n$.

Comment: I think I understand your proof but the two last inequalities. Should you have $a_{i,j}^2\ge a_{i,i} a_{j,j}$ ?

Comment: @Surb You only need $A$ to be symetric. The fact that $A$ is positive is required to have ${}^tX_{\lambda}AX_{\lambda}\geqslant 0$.

Comment: @JotadiolyneDicci No, the polynomial is always positive so its discriminant is negative.

Comment: Oh yeah so it should be : $4a_{i,j}^2-4a_{i,i}a_{j,j}\le 0$ ?

Comment: Well that was difficult ! We really need to use the min-max theorem. That's impressive.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to F5 to see my edit.

Comment: @Tuvasbien My bad !

Comment: Yes it is easier to read like that.